# Not able to receive Message from another user only able to send message users in a Chat Application (Similar like Whatsapp)

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I tried to develop a chat application similar like Whatsapp but when i tried to chat between 2 users they can only able to send messages and the chat data will sucessfully stored in the firebase but not shown in the another person
[Chat example when i sent that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTLP8.png) & [chat example where i'm not received the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxxxT.png)

I'm too beginner
Full source code in my [Github Reposatory](https://github.com/gauravmandall/WhatsappByGaurav)

MessageAdapter.java

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Message> messages;

    final int ITEM_SENT = 1;
    final int ITEM_RECEIVED = 2;


    public MessagesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages){
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == ITEM_SENT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_sent, parent, false);
            return new SentViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_receive, parent, false);
            return new RecieverViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equals(message.getSenderId())){
            return ITEM_SENT;
        }else {
            return ITEM_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);

        if (holder.getClass() == SentViewHolder.class){
            SentViewHolder viewHolder = (SentViewHolder)holder;
            viewHolder.binding.senderTxt.setText(message.getMessage());
        }else {
            RecieverViewHolder viewHolder = (RecieverViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.binding.receiverTxt.setText(message.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public class SentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ItemSentBinding binding;
        public SentViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = ItemSentBinding.bind(itemView);

        }
    }

    public class RecieverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ItemReceiveBinding binding;
        public RecieverViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = ItemReceiveBinding.bind(itemView);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to a repo is not enough, as links tend to rot over time. Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
please help me I'm so beginner please help me please please

Comment: W/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
this was the warning shown in logcat